# Soaking after using Riled Up

Tags: savage-worlds

We use the standard Adventure Cards in our Savage Worlds game. A character was wounded, then played Riled Up which is only activated on a wound, giving them +2 damage for the rest of the scene.

Next, though, the player spent a bennie and soaked the wound. I allowed it, but I'm wondering if this was proper. There seems to be no reason why the player can't do this in the RAW, but it seems wrong against the fluff of the card.

Was it OK for the character to soak their wound? If not, what should have happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a GM, I would have ruled that they could not have spent the benny after playing the card.

The wording of the rules under Soak Rolls in the core rules states that:

> A success and each raise reduces the number of wounds suffered from that attack by one

This means that character is assumed never to have had the wound in the first place. If this is the case, the criterion for activating the card was never met, and so it could not have been used.

So, in order to benefit from the +2 damage for the rest of the scene, the player has to take a wound that they cannot soak. If they soak the wound then they cannot play the card to activate the +2 damage.

Comment: Yep. In general, Soak means "the Wound never happened", not "you suddenly and miraculously healed the Wound".

Comment: What Dave said. Also I believe the same rationale applies for not getting a wound-induced ability from the Berserk Edge and HoER Don't Get 'Im Riled Edge.